# XMLA error with more than one value of the same dimension in WHERE

Tags: iccube

I found a problem with icCube and XMLA.

When performing a query through XMLA and the where we have more than one item of the same dimension disappears node **"SlicerAxis"** of the result.

Example:

If execute:

```
select 

        hierarchize({[Customers].[Geography].[All Regions],[Customers].[Geography].[All Regions].children}) on rows,
        [Measures].members on columns 
    from 
       [Sales]
    where {[Product].[Product].[All Products].[icCube].[Support].[Platinum]}
```

All OK.

In the XMLA output:

```
.....
<AxesInfo>
    <AxisInfo name="Axis0">
    .....
    </AxisInfo>
    <AxisInfo name="Axis1">
    .....   
    </AxisInfo>
    <AxisInfo name="SlicerAxis">
    .....   
    </AxisInfo>
</AxesInfo>
.....
```

But if we execute:

```
select 
    hierarchize({[Customers].[Geography].[All Regions],[Customers].[Geography].[All Regions].children}) on rows,
    [Measures].members on columns 
from 
   [Sales]
where {[Product].[Product].[All Products].[icCube].[Support].[Platinum],[Product].[Product].[All Products].[icCube].[Support].[Gold]}
```

XMLA output is:

```
.....
<AxesInfo>
    <AxisInfo name="Axis0">
    .....
    </AxisInfo>
    <AxisInfo name="Axis1">
    .....   
    </AxisInfo>
</AxesInfo>
.....
```

No node `<AxisInfo name="SlicerAxis">`

Some APIs XMLA like "jpivot" or "JasperReport net.sf.jasperreports.olap.xmla.JRXmlaQueryExecuterFactory" read AxesInfo information and hope that at least there SlicerAxis named node.
These APIS fail.

Excuse my English.

Greetings and thanks.

Juan

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem in Jpivot library XMLA parser. Easier to ask icCube team to fix this : there is already an issue in icCube's bug tracking system -> [here](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-36)